# PHP: No rows returned from MySQL database?

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm encountering a problem when retrieving rows from a MySql database with the InnoDB engine. First, I prepare about 50 random alphabetic inputs of several kilobytes each:

```
inputs <- generate(50, 2048)
```

Then, for each item in the collection of inputs, I try to post to a form handler:

```
def send_over(item):
    try:
        payload = {'variable': item}
        r = requests.post("http://localhost/handler.php", data=payload, timeout=1.000)    
        if not r:
            print("warning: could not post")
            print("\t", item)
            print()
            return False
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("Timeout. Could not post")
        print("\t", item)
        print()
        return False

    return True
```

Immediately after posting, I try to query the last row inserted, with

def check(cnc, item):

```
# "cnc" is a tuple that contains a connection (cnx) and cursor object
# This is from the Python/connector module.

cnx, cursor = cnc

if not cnx or not cursor:
    print("Problem connecting to database")
    return False

# get last row
query = ("select * from table order by primary_key desc")

# compare database entry with posted data    

cursor.execute(query)

for (primary_key, what) in cursor:
    if what != item:
        print("FAIL: data mismatch")
        return False

return True
```

But no rows are returned on query. Why might this be happening? The form handler uses PDO objects and prepared statements. Is there a way (in PHP) to make sure each INSERT is committed to the database? This is my only guess.

Comment: Can you view the DB and make sure there is actually stuff in there to return?

Comment: @IanAuld Hmm...queries may be taking place before insertion. Is there a way to wait (in PHP or Python) before making a query?

Comment: I don't know about PHP but in Python you can `import time` and then `time.sleep(TIME_IN_SECONDS)`

Comment: Still not working. Is autocommit done for PDO/prepared requests? I'd like to commit for every insertion.

Comment: You should be able to open the DB at any point and see what is in it. Doesn't PHPAdmin allow you to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44981/discussion-between-ianauld-and-user1505713)